# X509Store.Certificates.Find with validOnly to true is not returning Intermediate authority certificate

Tags: c#, azure, x509certificate

I had a certificate installed on:

- Certificates (Local Computer)

  - Trusted root Certification Authorities

    - Certificates

And this code got the certificate as valid.

```
X509Store certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.CertificateAuthority, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
certStore.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly | OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

try {
    var oAuthRootCertificateList = certStore.Certificates.Find(findType, findValue, true);
    oauthRootCertificate = oAuthRootCertificateList[0];
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Trace.TraceError(ex.Message);
} finally {
    certStore.Close();
}
```

**(findType and findValue are set previously in the code)*

All was ok and the code was fine.

Now I have deleted the certificate from 'trusted root certification authorities' and installed on:

- Certificates (Local Computer)

  - Intermediate Certification Authorities

    - Certificates

because Azure doesn't let me to deploy the certificate on the Trusted Root branch.

And now, the code is failing.  I must to change the last parameter (validOnly) from `true` to `false` to get it to run.

You can see the help for the `Find` method [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2collection.find.aspx).

Any idea why is it not running and how I can solve it?

Comment: Why is that you are moving your certificate from Trusted Root Authorities to Intermediate Certificate? Is this a self signed certificate?

Comment: @Rajesh  From the question: "because Azure doesn't let me to deploy the certificate on the Trusted Root branch."

Comment: Please refer the following links which might be helpful: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winservercore/thread/5a613754-0a7f-4157-bc47-97e8b55a2878/ and http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/96926ae6-0cbf-4d00-9dd4-bbe86f93737e

Comment: this one also : http://leastprivilege.com/2011/03/01/adding-a-certificate-to-the-root-certificate-store-from-the-command-line-e-g-as-an-azure-startup-task/

Comment: I already knew the "manual-install" alternative, thanks @Rajesh  But I would like to know why the code thinks the certificate is not valid when it is located as an intermediate authority.

Comment: The certificates in the intermediate store are used only during the certificate chain validation purpose. If your certificate is a self signed certificate then its issuer need to be present in trusted root authority for the certificate validation to succeed. Just placing it in the intermediate certificate authority would not be enough

Comment: Please @Rajesh, put your last comment as an answer to accepted it.  It is what I was looking for.  An explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The certificates in the intermediate store are used for certificate chain validation purpose. If your certificate is a self signed certificate then its issuer need to be present in trusted root authority for the certificate validation to succeed.

Just placing it in the intermediate certificate authority would not be enough.